How to overcome PhD anxiety?
Background/Context: I'm a PhD Operations Research student going through my first year of the program. While my BS and MA is in Mathematics (strongly focusing/only in OR), and I've published quite a bit of research before, I have never really done pure Mathematics nor can I really comprehend it. Two out of my four courses will involve it. These two courses will be on the qualifying exam, and my entire degree is contingent on me passing it. Additionally, I was put as a TA on an applied stats class I've never taken before, so I've been speed running studying that.
Even though this is my first week, I'm filled with dread every waking minute of the day, and I'm constantly studying almost every waking hour. Personally, I feel as if this is an abyss I cannot get out of in terms of comprehension and difficulty as I'm studying way ahead in these courses - in that once the courses catches up to the point I'm at, I'll be screwed, as I don't know enough nor can comprehend enough, say Measure Theory as that's one of them, to get me by.
My question is: How does one overcome this PhD anxiety?

‘Personally, I feel as if this is an abyss I cannot get out of …’ After one week? What guidance did your advisor give you?

I've been studying the course materials all summer, and I knew the content I was getting into a year in advance. I've been studying and studying daily and don't feel like I've made progress mentally. I haven't talked to my advisor yet as I do not want to bother them over something that would waste their time

can you check with anyone with the knowledge that the course material you are using is too difficult or average level? I must say previously in one course, one exam question is a proof that the professor is sticking in his research, and the material is full of his recent research results..

If it becomes debilitating then you need to talk to a professional. Most large (i.e. doctoral) universities will have a way to do this through some office.
But, while it is natural to be anxious, you need a strategy to get through the hard bits. I'd suggest not taking the most difficult courses in the same term so that you can focus. If you are permitted to take the qualifiers one at a time, do that so that, again, you can focus. Do not (DO NOT) stay up all night cramming before a qualifier.
Ask a lot of questions in class. Others in the class likely have the same questions but are often hesitant to ask. I was once thought sort of brilliant because I asked so many questions. Try to solve more exercises than the minimum.
Learn to take breaks. Aerobic exercise during those breaks is a really good thing. If you exhaust yourself mentally it won't be helpful. Hourly breaks may not be too often. Get enough sleep. Your brain still works when sleeping or riding a bike.
Note, also, that you probably don't need grad level knowledge of a topic to TA for an elementary class. You might be able to meet with other TAs in the subject to boost your learning.
Your anxiety should subside over time if you have a good plan and start to see success in it.
